# Invalid column name 'allocationStart'

Tags: asp.net, sql

For whatever reason, I'm getting the error "Invalid column name `allocationStart`" when trying to execute a query. This is within the `dateadd` function, and the column DOES exist in the database. it is a `datetime`.

Here is the query:

```
cmd.commandText = "Insert Into EmpPac 
                     (catalogIdent, empPacIdent, empIdent, allocation, 
                      quantityLimit, quantityIssued, quantityShipped, 
                      allocationMonths, sizeChartIdent, sizeNotes, nextUpdate)
                     values ( '" & catalogIdent & "', '" & intvalue_EmpPak 
                      & "', '" & empIdent & "',"&jobQuantityLimit&",'"
                      &jobQuantityLimit&"', '0', '0',"&
                      allocationMonths&", '"& sizeChartident & 
                      "', '', DATEADD(month, "&allocationMonths&
                      ", allocationStart))"
cmd.execute
```

Comment: First of all, does your query works in Managment studio? Then, use SqlParameter and not string cacatenation, for many reasons, especially you won't have to deal with parameter type, and you will avoid Sql Injection attack

Comment: Are you sure this is ASP.NET and not classic ASP?

Comment: And you really need to lookup [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)

Comment: What is collation of your database?

Comment: By the way, column names are not permitted in VALUES section of insert statements. Valid expressions are constants, constant expressions, and (in some contexts) variables

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You don't specify what table `allocationstart` is in.**

You need to make your `INSERT` source be a `SELECT` from your source table, not using the `VALUES` keyword since that expects a list of explicit values.

For instance:

```
INSERT INTO MyTargetTable
SELECT <stuff>, DATEADD(month, XXX, allocationstart)
FROM MySourceDataTable
```

Answer (score 0):

I'll be honest - I'm not following your question 100% however I think I understand what you're trying to do.

The original error is originating at the DATEADD command.

The third parameter to DATEADD is a datetime value to manipulate.

I'm guessing your "allocationStart" column sets the current date time automatically within the DB, and your passing that column to the DATEADD function to manipulate it and insert the returned value into the "nextUpdate" column.  If this is what you're trying to do, the auto datetime column won't be set (able to return date / time etc) until the row is committed, you cannot therefore use auto=generated columns within function from inside an INSERT statement.

I would also strongly suggest you look at paramaters, its much safer and better practise.

If you're after the month number for the "nextUpdate" column, you could use DateTime.Now.Month and append that to your SQL string.